# iPhone Simulator:Just show Default img and finish the delegate method appDidFinishLaunching after quit iPhone Simulator and rebuild

Tags: iphone, sdk

After I quit simulator and click build the app from XCode, the iPhone Simulator loading and my app will be install and run. But the app just show only Default image (finish the applicationDidFinishLaunching method - I logs it) and do nothing. I can't do anything in Simulator, event click the "Home" button of Simulator. But the other time, when Simulator already running, I select the "Build" button in XCode and everything is fine. 
Can you tell me why and how does this issue effect my app when I build it with real device?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset iPhone simulator.

Comment: restart iPhone Simulator, restart XCode and restart your Mac and everything should work fine

Comment: Thanks Nickolay, I try it but at the first time I build (the first time loading Simulator), It still happen. (It's just occur at the first time, other time is OK). And I wonder that how it effect with the device build?

Comment: That's probably a bug in iPhone simulator. That happens sometimes with xCode as well (yeah, Apple apps are not bug-free). This will not affect real device, since simulator is just another program, not the real device.